# Responsive sizing of my chart in dimple.js is not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, dimple.js

I have an svg component on my page to which I have appended my dimple chart. I want the chart to be sized responsively.

I have referred to this [example](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_responsive_sizing) in the documentation.

But when I use it in a similar fashion in my line chart, it does not seem to work. My code for a line chart is as follows:

```
                    var xpoints = chartData["xdata"];//Populated Dynamically
                    var ypoints = chartData["ydata"];//Populated Dynamically


                    var dataset = [];
                    var line1;

                    for (var i = 0; i < xpoints.length; i++) {

                            dataset.push({
                                x : xpoints[i],
                                y1 : parseFloat(ypoints[i])
                            });
                        }

                    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#" + mychart, "100%", "100%");

                    var x, y;

                    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, dataset);

                    myChart.setMargins("60px", "30px", "110px", "70px");

                    y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "y1");
                    x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "x");

                    line1 = myChart.addSeries("First", dimple.plot.line, [ x, y ]);

                    line1.lineMarkers = true;

                    var l = myChart.addLegend(65, 10, 510, 20, "right");

                    myChart.draw(1500);

                      window.onresize = function () {
                            myChart.draw(0, true);
                          };
```

Is it that I cannot do this in the same window itself and it is absolutely necessary for me to create a new window, as in the example?

The console does not show any errors, the chart is rendered correctly. It's just that the resize function does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found my mistake!

> Turns out there is no need to create a new window.

It's just that, I had explicitly defined the height and width of the div (#mychart) to which I was appending my svg and these dimensions were in pixels. So the size of the svg remained the same even on window resize - **because it was always 100% of a constant pixel value**. So the function was actually firing earlier as well, but was ending up with the same dimensions.

I changed the dimensions of my div to percentage values and everything works fine :D